# Significant drop in Google search apperance after switch to https

Tags: .htaccess, https, seo, cloudflare

I have what I can say is a huge problem. I have a website that I've switched to `https` using Cloudflare and it almost completely disappeared from Google search results.

Here is my `.htaccess`

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

So I have 301, but did I do it right?

Answer (score 1):

Google may some time to reindex.  According to this [discussion on Moz](http://moz.com/community/q/redirecting-http-to-https-how-long-does-it-take-google-to-re-index-the-site), it may take a day for important URLs to 90 days for less important URLs to be indexed.

Other than that, it seems that you have only just changed the .htaccess to 301 redirect all URLs to the https one.

Have you:

1. check Google Webmaster Tools to see if the site has been indexed and for any error messages?
2. Changed the links in the sitemap.xml to the https one?
3. Updated the rel=canonical tag?
4. Changed all the internal URLs to  https?
5. Updated other rel tags like rel=next, rel=previous and rel=alternate?
6. Updated all the external URLs you control, like Facebook/ Twitter?
7. Updated things like open-graph tags and social media widgets, so that new link juice can be passed on to the new https site when others share on social sites?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to indicate in GWT that you would prefer to use https://.